# Ctags: finding a common function name

Tags: vim, ctags

I noticed my ctags floods my screen with potential results of a definition if the function name I'm looking for is something commonly named such as `write`. To elaborate:

```
class SunsetHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def on_response(self, response):
        if response.error:
            self.write(response.error)
```

Calling ctags on `write`(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>) returns many results, when the only `write` I'm interested in should be from `tornado.web.RequestHandler`.

I get something like the following, where this time only the top result is the result I'm looking for:

```
   # pri kind tag               file
  1 F   m    write             env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/wsgi.py
               language:Python class:_WSGIConnection
               def write(self, chunk, callback=None):
  2 F   m    write             env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httputil.py
               language:Python class:HTTPServerRequest
               def write(self, chunk, callback=None):
  3 F   m    write             env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httputil.py
               language:Python class:HTTPConnection
               def write(self, chunk, callback=None):
  4 F   m    write             env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py
               language:Python class:RequestHandler
               def write(self, chunk):
  5 F   m    write             env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py
               language:Python class:BaseIOStream
               def write(self, data, callback=None):
  6 F   m    write             env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py
               language:Python class:HTTP1Connection
               def write(self, chunk, callback=None):
  7     v    WRITE             env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py
               language:Python class:IOLoop
               WRITE = _EPOLLOUT
```

How can I isolate the query, other than manually pruning the ctags exclusion list of directories? Even if I add the following, there can be several results in a large repo, for `self.write`:

`ctags -R --fields=+l --languages=python --python-kinds=-iv -f ./tags --exclude='env' env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/*`

Answer (score 0):

Ctags itself already contains that information (you can see the `class:RequestHandler` tag in the 4th result).

The problem is at the editor level: in order to tell ctags it's looking for the instance in `RequestHandler`, vim would have to be able to parse the file you're in, determine that `self` is a `tornado.web.RequestHandler`, and then pass that into the ctags lookup. Vim can't do that, and as far as I know there aren't any plugins to add that ability except via things like [eclim](http://eclim.org/) which aren't using ctags at all anymore.